# Can I have a legend of CLion project pane coloring?

Tags: ide, clion

I have the following picture in Project pane:

[image]

As you see, I have red, green, blue, white and dirty green colors of text. Also I have white and red colors on folder icons. Also I have some items background highlighted.

Is there any easy way to know what it all means?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is: [File Status Highlights](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/file-status-highlights.html).

Most frequently used colors are:

- green: added to source control, not committed yet;
- black or white, depending on light/dark theme: under source control, unchanged;
- blue: under source control, changed locally;
- brown or red: not under source control.

Red folder icon and a yellowish background in this folder mean "excluded from CLion search indexing".